# Is it possible to have an alias for the function name in Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp

...just like packages do.

I use Emacs (maybe, it can offer some kind of solution).

For example `(defun the-very-very-long-but-good-name () ...)` is not to useful later in code. But the name like `Fn-15` or the first letters abbreviation is not useful too.
Is it possible either to have an alias like for packages or to access the documentation string while trying to recall the function's name?

In other words, is it possible for functions to mix somehow self-documenting and short names?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You want `defalias`. `(defalias 'newname 'oldname)` will preserve documentation and even show "newname is an alias for `oldname'" when its documentation is requested.

Comment: Ctrl-H f defalias well get you wehre you need to go.

Comment: The above should be (defalias 'newname 'oldname) .

Comment: `defalias` is an Elisp function - given @avp's comment above it sounds  like they are using common-lisp

Comment: verdammelt, you are completely right, I confused the environments. But it was soo long ago...  
Actually, despite this answer is completely correct and I accept it, it is easier to use hippie-expand in case I don't care for size of the code.

Answer (score 5):

from 《On Lisp》？Here is the code:

```
(defmacro alias (new-name prev-name)
  `(defmacro ,new-name (&rest args)
     `(,',prev-name ,@args)))

; use: (alias df defun)


(defun group (source n)
  (if (zerop n) (error "zero length"))
  (labels ((rec (source acc)
             (let ((rest (nthcdr n source)))
               (if (consp rest)
                   (rec rest (cons (subseq source 0 n) acc))
                   (nreverse (cons source acc))))))
    (if source (rec source nil) nil)))

(defmacro aliasx (&rest names)
  `(alias
     ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (pair)
                   `(alias ,@pair))
               (group names 2))))

; use: (aliasx df1 defun 
;              df2 defun 
;              df3 defun)
```

Comment: Thanks, muyinliu, for input, but Allen already answered the question. OTOH, this solution requires me to remember the unnecessary details, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `setf` to assign the function to the function cell of another, for example:

```
(defmacro alias (new-name prev-name)
  `(setf (symbol-function ,new-name) (symbol-function ,prev-name)))
```

Comment: This doesn't even really need to be a macro `(defun alias (new-name prev-name) (setf (symbol-function new-name) (symbol-function prev-name)))` works too.

Answer (score 4):

If it's all the typing which makes continual use of long names undesirable, then yes, emacs can help.  Check out [`abbrev-mode`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(emacs)Abbrevs).  Also well thought-of in this context is [`hippie-expand`](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/HippieExpand).

If it's a question of readability, that's harder.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you can't remember a very long function name, but you remember PART of the name, that's what "apropos" is for.  In my Emacs, I have "C-h a" bound to "hyper-apropos".  You enter a substring of the symbol you're looking for, and it lists all the matches.

Comment: My problem is that I want both short names and descriptions, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Emacs, but wouldn't (define shortname longnamefunctionblahblah) work?

Comment: Well... First, it is not automatic. Second, I need to care about it myself. Third, it is clunky... :(

Answer (score -1):

You could simply have a function that just calls another function.

Comment: You would loose documentation then.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `(defmacro ...)` to alias a function

Comment: I'd repeat what I've said to leppie. It is just... I don't know... It looks ugly. I mean, it takes effort, but provides just readability. Abbrev-mode  & hippie-expand does similar job effortless... But anyway, thanks for input!