# How to let a second symbol refer to a function

Tags: emacs, clojure, elisp

In Clojure I can let a second symbol refer to a function.

```
(defn sq [x] (* x x))
(sq 7)
```

-> 49

```
(def square sq)
(square 7)
```

-> 49

In Emacs-Lisp, I only know about

```
(defun square (x) (sq x))
```

Is there a solution nearer in spirit to the first one?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192049/is-it-possible-to-have-an-alias-for-the-function-name-in-lisp , see 2nd answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun sq (x) (* x x))
(defalias 'square 'sq)
```